# Where can I see an Apollo spacecraft?

Tags: sightseeing, where-on-earth, museums, geek-travel

Is there any museum that has a Apollo spacecraft that I can visit? I'm interested in this kind of spacecrafts because they have a really impressive history, e.g. they are said to be used for the first moon landing.

I would prefer a museum in Europe, but USA would also be okay.

Comment: Well, the first *crewed* moon landing was Apollo. The Soviets made the [first moon landing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moon_landing#Uncrewed_landings) in 1959 with [Luna 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luna_2), having missed the target with [Luna 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luna_1).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The capsules from Soyuz - Apollo flight used to be and the Apollo 11 command module is at the [Smithsonian Air and Space Museum](http://www.si.edu/Museums/air-and-space-museum) in Washington, DC.

A quick search also gives a list of all remaining [Apollo spacecraft and their locations](http://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/planetary/lunar/apolloloc.html) based on that there is only one in Europe in London.

Comment: The London Science Museum also has a full size replica of the Apollo 11 Eagle lander.

Answer (score 9):

*The* museum for all things space, including just so, SO much from Apollo and other missions - is the [Kennedy Space Center](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kennedy_Space_Center) in Florida.  Highly recommend it!

Even just seeing their "rocket garden" is incredible, but all the Apollo stuff, including a GIGANTIC Saturn V rocket you can walk under as it hangs horizontally in a large hanger is amazing.  Go to the actual Apollo moon landing control room.  And see the Shuttle pads, Vehicle Assembly Building (4th largest in world by volume), and even meet past astronauts.

Now as for your specific question, you'd go to the building with the Saturn V rocket called the [Apollo / Saturn V center](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo/Saturn_V_Center#Apollo.2FSaturn_V_Center).  In addition to the rocket, there's the Apollo 14 command module, an unused service module and an unused Lunar module.

Comment: Can I there also see the scene where they made the moon-landing video?

Comment: @RoflcoptrException - There are 6 main studios that were used to make the moon-landing videos. All are quite a long way away from KSC. They are located at the Sea of Tranquility, the Ocean of Storms, Fra Mauro, Hadley Rille, Descartes & Taurus-Littrow. If you are unable to make the journey to visit them yourself you can do the next best thing and visit several of them by proxy by bouncing a LASER beam off the corner reflectors at a number of the sites. These allow you to be certain that you are in fact visiting a site that has indisputably been visited before.

Comment: +1 from me for this.  I'm a child of the moon program, though European: one of my earliest memories is staying up really late, aged 2, to watch Apollo 11 land.  Walking down the whole length of the (completely genuine) Saturn V launch vehicle at Kennedy is one of the more moving experiences of my life; properly, properly impressive.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon, yes, Stanley Kubrick was quite insistent about filming on location.

Answer (score 6):

[Field Guide to American Spacecraft](https://www.americanspacecraft.com/pages/apollo/index.html) is a great resource for this.  There are many, many spacecraft in various museums, and quite a few of the test modules and mockups have been restored to better condition than they started, so that they can be display pieces.

The spacecraft in Europe are:

- [A Gemini test vehicle](https://www.americanspacecraft.com/pages/gemini/TTV-2.html) at the National Museum of Scotland.
- [Apollo 10 command module](https://www.americanspacecraft.com/pages/apollo/A-10.html) at the [Science Museum](http://www.sciencemuseum.org.uk/) in London.

Answer (score 2):

## Evergreen Museum, Oregon

The [*Evergreen Aviation & Space Museum*](https://www.evergreenmuseum.org/) in [McMinnville Oregon US](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McMinnville%2C_Oregon) has several items related to Apollo missions.

Their [Space Flight exhibits page](https://www.evergreenmuseum.org/space-flight) lists:

- Boosters

  - Rocketdyne H-1 Rocket Engine Used on the Saturn 1 and Saturn 1b boosters
  - Pratt & Whitney RL-10 Rocket Engine. Utilized in the upper stage of the Saturn I.
  - Rocketdyne J-2 Rocket Engine. One of the critical components of the Saturn V rocket that took astronauts to the Moon.
- Spacecraft

  - [Mercury Space Capsule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Mercury#Spacecraft) (on loan)
  - [Lunar Roving Vehicle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunar_Roving_Vehicle) (Replica)
  - [Apollo Lunar Module](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo_Lunar_Module) Replica
  - [Apollo Command Module](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo_command_and_service_module#Command_Module_(CM)) Replica
  - [Gemini Spacecraft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Gemini) (Replica)
  - [Saturn V Instrument Unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturn_V_instrument_unit)

Plus Soviet items: [Sputnik](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sputnik_1) Replica, [Lunokhod 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunokhod_2) Replica, [Foton 6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foton_(satellite)) Capsule (an unmanned version of the Vostok capsule used to launch Yuri Gargarin).

Add to that Space Museum their Aviation Museum, with the actual [Spruce Goose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hughes_H-4_Hercules), other interesting planes (many in working condition!), and you have a memorable place to visit.